# TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'monitor' in mxnet python

Tags: mxnet

When I run the example/image-classification/train_mnist.py, I was told that `TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'monitor'`. I have change nothing in this file. And I have just download the latest version from the github.

```
example\image-classification>python train_mnist.py
INFO:root:start with arguments Namespace(batch_size=64, disp_batches=100, gpus=N
one, kv_store='device', load_epoch=None, lr=0.05, lr_factor=0.1, lr_step_epochs=
'10', model_prefix=None, mom=0.9, monitor=0, network='mlp', num_classes=10, num_
epochs=20, num_examples=60000, num_layers=None, optimizer='sgd', test_io=0, top_
k=0, wd=0.0001)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_mnist.py", line 76, in <module>
    fit.fit(args, sym, get_mnist_iter)
  File "D:\Zhenxingjian\MxNet\mxnet-0.9.3\mxnet-0.9.3\example\image-classificati
on\common\fit.py", line 183, in fit
    monitor            = monitor)
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'monitor'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully run train_mnist.py example on v09.3, v0.9.5 and v0.10.0. If the problem still persists for you, maybe checkout the latest version and try again.